# Recommended way to provide users with a Terms and Conditions dialog?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I would like to know what is the recommended means of showing a T&C dialog? A simple AlertDialog? Furthermore how can I prevent this dialog from showing on each startup? Would I need to use SharedPreferences to store a boolean (accepted\not accepted) or is there a simpler method? I'm trying to get a feel for the communities recommended approaches to some of the more common situations in android.

Comment: You could do a popup with a link to a web page with your terms (formatted for viewing on a mobile device). Then you don't have to worry about displaying the Terms within the application.

Comment: Or, if you only worried about HAVING the terms and not necessarily presenting them with it, then you could include it in the settings such that you click on it in the settings and it opens up a view for the user to read them.

Comment: Yeah I need to ask the client to clarify. I guess having it as a separate view does simplify things. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing it in my app, but more complex. I have a web services in Java to get last terms for locale in database. In android app I'm creating a sqlite table for terms with terms_id, terms_description and locale. terms_id in order desc define my last terms. I get default locale on android with Locale.getDefault().toString(). If the query don't return a terms, then I'm calling web service passing no terms_id and android locale. If the query return a terms, I'm getting the last one and calling web service passing the terms_id returned by query, locale for terms and android locale if it is different of in database. Web services validate if terms_id from android is the last in the database. If no, then it get the last one for android locale, or, if no having a terms for android locale, then it get the last one for default locale (en_US). If terms_id on android is the same of database, then web services validate if locale of android exists in database returning this version, otherwise it returns version for locale default. If terms already exists in correct version or default version on android mobile, then web services returns a code indicating that version is ok. After it, I save the terms, if need, in table of terms.

I'm searching now for the best way to show the terms. I think I will create a translucent Activity to create a window with a panel to show the terms and two buttons "Accept" and "Reject". If the user accept the terms I will call another web services to mark on the server that user has accept this version of terms. In the future, I can update the terms in web database creating a new version and when user login on mobile app I will call a web service to login and verify if user has accept the last version of terms and returning a new version if not, then, I will show a message for user to read and to accept the new version of terms.

Best regards.